# HBase fetch data in sorted order based on last updated time

Tags: hbase

Before going directly to issue, let me give some background.

I am using hbase as my nosql storage. I am interfacing with hbase using java hbase API. I am storing user information in which one of the column is action performed by a user. Whenever a user does some action we are updating that particular action in action column and updating last updated time column with time when action gets performed. My row looks like

> reverse_time_stamp#user_id (here i am calculating reverse_time_stamp = max_number_in_java -
>    current_time_stamp)

Now here comes my problem, I have to fetch user list based on last updated time, so users which have performed some action recently should get fetched first. For this what I am doing right now is, whenever a user performs some action I am deleting previous row, copying that row data to another row with generating new key with updated reverse time stamp. By doing this I am always getting latest users who performed some action at top my scan.

As every time a user perform some action i am deleting existing row and creating another row, is their any other way to do it?

My user count can be in millions. I update actions every time user take any action like click.

Comment: Hello Sachin , why do you have to delete that user row ? , can you not update the reverse TS + user as a new row ?

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G I want so fetch users based on action performed time. So i am creating row with last updated time as prefix in row key. If i don't delete older row, it will get fetched in my scan. So for single user there can be multiple entries. To avoid this, i am deleting old row.